# R script: While using shift function in data.table - errror: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, data.table, lag

I  have data.table

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(Shift = c(c(0,0,0,1,2,1,1)),
              Value = rnorm(7),I.Value = rnorm(7))
dat
Shift      Value    I.Value
 0       -0.6264538  0.7383247
 0        0.1836433  0.5757814
 0       -0.8356286 -0.3053884
 1        1.5952808  1.5117812
 2        0.3295078  0.3898432
 1       -0.8204684 -0.6212406
 1        0.4874291 -2.2146999
```

I want the new column to be shift(Value,Shift,fill=0). Hence the result should be-

```
  Shift      Value    I.Value    new.value   new.I.value
   0       -0.6264538  0.7383247  -0.6264538  0.7383247
   0        0.1836433  0.5757814   0.1836433  0.5757814
   0       -0.8356286 -0.3053884   -0.8356286 -0.3053884
   1        1.5952808  1.5117812    0           0
   2        0.3295078  0.3898432   1.5952808  1.5117812
   1       -0.8204684 -0.6212406    0           0
   1        0.4874291 -2.2146999   0.3295078  0.3898432
```

What I have till now:

```
dat[,`:=` (new.value= shift(Value,Shift,fill = 0),
         new.I.value=shift(I.Value,Shift,fill = 0))]
```

But the shift function is returning a list as the parameter Shift is not of length 1, but the entire vector. Hence I face the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dat[Shift == 0, `:=`(new = Value)], !Shift ==  : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I tried passing Shift[.I], but did not work either.

How do i pass just the row value of the column Shift, such that a vector is returned and I get the proper result? 
As my working dataset is pretty huge, I prefer working with data.table.

---

**Edit:**

-The output generated by the above function is -

```
   Shift       Value    I.Value grp       new2       new3
1:     0 -1.22461261  1.7672873   1 -1.2246126  1.7672873
2:     0 -0.47340064  0.7167075   1 -0.4734006  0.7167075
3:     0 -0.62036668  0.9101742   1 -0.6203667  0.9101742
4:     1  0.04211587  0.3841854   2  0.0000000  0.0000000
5:     2 -0.91092165  1.6821761   3  0.0000000  0.0000000
6:     1  0.15802877 -0.6357365   4  0.0000000  0.0000000
7:     1 -0.65458464 -0.4616447   4  0.1580288 -0.6357365
```

4th row should have been shifted to 5th as `dat$Shift[4]==1` and 5th row should have been shifted to 7th as `dat$Shift[5]==2`. If we simply write-

```
dat[,new:=shift(Value,2,fill=0),new.I:=shift(I.Value,2,fill=0)]
```

will shift all rows down by 2 as n=2, just instead of a hardcoded value, n has to be the value present in the column 'Shift' for current row under process.

Comment: What is `Shift` in the `shift` call?

Comment: Did you meant `Shift` as `n`?

Comment: I"m not sure your desired output is very clear, can you please show how did you arrive to the results in the last four rows please?

Comment: I believe that when shift=2, the row should be shifted down by two. This however causes some rows to have two possible values (row 5+2=7, and row 6+1 = also 7). So row 7 has two possible values?

Comment: Please show if there is any problem in the expected output.

Comment: Comment by Riya on my deleted answer: @akrun 'Shift' is the column in 'dat' datatable by which 'Value' must be shifted, so yes 'Shift' is n. Row 4 should be shifted down by one, and row 5 should be shifted down by two. If there are 2 possible values ( which is a possible scenario), the latest value will be placed in the cell.

Comment: @akrun Going row-wise, the values in Value column must be shifted by the value in 'Shift' column. If two possible values (possible scenario), latest value must be kept.

Comment: It seems you are keeping the first value? Row 7 has been replaced with row 5, rather than row 6.

Comment: That is because Shift value is 2 for row 5, hence moves down by 2 to row 7. NAs become 0.

Comment: @Riya I think your shift for 2 will be shifted two.  In the expected, it is not.  Perhaps `nm1 <- grep("Value", names(dat))
;dat[, grp := rleid(Shift)][, paste0("new", nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) shift(x, n = Shift[1L], fill = 0)), grp, .SDcols = nm1 ]`

Comment: And the shift value is 1 for row 6, so it also moves down to row 7. The last one of these two is 6, but row 7 is replaced with row 5.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work ?

Note that I give priority to the value in row 5, as the value in row 6 would be shifted to the same position.

```
shift2 <- function(val,shift,fill){
  new_val <- rep(fill,length(val))
  indices <- (1:length(val))+shift
  indices <- indices[indices <= nrow(dat)]
  new_val[rev(indices)]= val[length(indices):1]
  new_val
}

dat[,`:=` (new.value= shift2(Value,Shift,fill = 0),
           new.I.value=shift2(I.Value,Shift,fill = 0))]

# > dat
#    Shift      Value    I.Value  new.value new.I.value
# 1:     0 -0.6264538  0.7383247 -0.6264538   0.7383247
# 2:     0  0.1836433  0.5757814  0.1836433   0.5757814
# 3:     0 -0.8356286 -0.3053884 -0.8356286  -0.3053884
# 4:     1  1.5952808  1.5117812  0.0000000   0.0000000
# 5:     2  0.3295078  0.3898432  1.5952808   1.5117812
# 6:     1 -0.8204684 -0.6212406  0.0000000   0.0000000
# 7:     1  0.4874291 -2.2146999  0.3295078   0.3898432
```

If you want to prioritize row 6 over row 5 :

```
shift3 <- function(val,shift,fill){
  new_val <- rep(fill,length(val))
  indices <- (1:length(val))+shift
  indices <- indices[indices <= nrow(dat)]
  new_val[indices]= val[1:length(indices)]
  new_val
}

dat[,`:=` (new.value= shift3(Value,Shift,fill = 0),
          new.I.value=shift3(I.Value,Shift,fill = 0))]
# 
# Shift      Value    I.Value  new.value new.I.value
# 1:     0 -0.6264538  0.7383247 -0.6264538   0.7383247
# 2:     0  0.1836433  0.5757814  0.1836433   0.5757814
# 3:     0 -0.8356286 -0.3053884 -0.8356286  -0.3053884
# 4:     1  1.5952808  1.5117812  0.0000000   0.0000000
# 5:     2  0.3295078  0.3898432  1.5952808   1.5117812
# 6:     1 -0.8204684 -0.6212406  0.0000000   0.0000000
# 7:     1  0.4874291 -2.2146999 -0.8204684  -0.6212406
```

Comment: This works!! Thanks! If the requirement changes to the last row being as follows, how do I change the function shift2(). i.e. I keep 6th row instead of 5th.
 `Shift      Value    I.Value    new.value   new.I.value
   1        0.4874291 -2.2146999   -0.8204684 -0.6212406`

Comment: I edited my answer for this possibility, it all happens in the fourth line of the function's body, values are recovered in the given order.

Comment: This is fantastic! I am new to data.table so this was a great learning exp for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help, my answer only uses bases R though, not `data.table` :). If the answer satisfies you please consider validating the answer (green v mark next to the vote)