# Shifting datatable rows by indices

Tags: r, data.table

While trying to answer [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139456/r-script-while-using-shift-function-in-data-table-errror-list-object-canno), I ran into my own separate question, which I am unable to solve myself. However, I am really curious to find an efficient solution for my problem. I initially posted this as an answer to that question, but since it caused confusion I  think it is a better decision to post this question separately:

Suppose I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.table(value = seq(1,7),value2 = seq(1,7))
shift_id = c(1,2,3,NA,4,NA,5)
```

And I want to use the shift_id to shift rows into two new columns, so the desired output is:

```
   value value2 value1.shift value2.shift
1:     1      1            1            1
2:     2      2            2            2
3:     3      3            3            3
4:     4      4            NA            NA
5:     5      5            4            4
6:     6      6            NA            NA
7:     7      7            5            5
```

Notice that row 7 has the contents of row 5, since shift_id[7]=5
How would I do this efficiently with the DT package?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is basically a base R feature of subsetting a vector by it's location. Doesn't look like data.table related.

Comment: That's true, I was just wondering how to do it with the DT package. Thanks for your feedback on the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
dat[, c("value1.shift", "value2.shift") := list(dat$value[shift_id], dat$value2[shift_id])]

 > dat
   value value2 value1.shift value2.shift
1:     1      1            1            1
2:     2      2            2            2
3:     3      3            3            3
4:     4      4           NA           NA
5:     5      5            4            4
6:     6      6           NA           NA
7:     7      7            5            5
```

Another more generic approach which uses data table specific functionalities (thanks to @David Arenburg for the suggestion) would be:

```
dat[, paste0(names(dat)[grepl("value", names(dat))], ".shift") := lapply(.SD, `[`, shift_id), .SDcols = grep("value", names(dat))]
```

Comment: You probably don't need `dat$`. And could generalize using `lapply`, `.SD` , `paste` and `.SDcols`.

Comment: True, I will add it in the answer! Thank you for the suggestion.